# Why does TypeScript's 'declare global' cause ESLint error?

Tags: typescript, eslint

So, I have this global interface Window at the top of the .ts file:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {myOwnName: string;}
}
```

I need this because I want to assign new values to the window property.

Code works, but ESLint gives me this error: **Parsing error, unexpected token.**

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas how to fix this? In my eslint.json config I do use such configuration:

```
config = {
    common: {
        settings: {
            'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
            'plugins': [
                '@typescript-eslint',
                'import'
            ],
            'rules': {
                'import/no-unresolved': 'error'
            },
            'import/resolver': {
                'typescript': {},
                'node': {
                    'moduleDirectory': [
                        'node_modules/',
                        'src/',
                        'proto/gen/'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just remove the line `declare global {` and the closing bracket `}`. And put the content in a `global.d.ts` file.

Comment: @Paleo okay, I did it, but now IDE tells me that "Window interface is never used" and also I have errors when I am assigning new values to window

Comment: Looks like a bug, nothing wrong with using `declare global`

Comment: Or maybe the issue is with ESLint only? Could you try with TSLint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config file is probably not being picked up correctly. Eslint config files must be named as one of `.eslintrc`, `.eslintrc.{js,json,yaml,yml}`. Also your config object is not in the schema expected by Eslint.

Comment: What is the schema expected by eslint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one line in your config file `.eslintrc`:

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```